# Setting an Unordered list as inline even when collapsed *Bootstrap*

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am lately getting into bootstrap and I'm trying to code a simple website. The following is the code for the **navbar**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

I want the first div (the one with the social media) to remain inline whenever the navbar collapses. I have tried to override the bootstrap CSS and set it to **float: left;**

I have also tried to **pull-left** on the div and **pull-right** on the unordered list.

This is the navbar before it is collapsed:
[Navbar Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75RLh.png)

And this is the image of the navbar after it collapses:
[Navbar Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPGcg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a div in your header (not with Bootstrap classes as they will conflict with what you're trying to do) and apply the CSS that's appropriate.

See working example.

```css
body,
html {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.navbar-header .nav-icons {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.navbar-header .nav-icons i {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.navbar-header .nav-icons a {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-header .nav-icons {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <div class="nav-icons">
        <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i>
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <!-- Non-collapsing right-side icons -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well well-lg">Boostrap Mobile</div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response!